# Can bootstrap resampling be used to calculate a confidence interval for the variance of a dataset?

Tags: distributions, confidence-interval, bootstrap, resampling

I know that if you re-sample from a data set many times and calculate the mean each time, these means will follow a normal distribution (by the CLT). Thus, you can calculate a confidence interval on the mean of the data set without making any assumptions on the probability distribution of the data set.

I was wondering if you could do something similar for the variance. That is, if I were to re-sample from a data set many times and calculate the variance each time, would these variances follow a certain distribution (regardless of what the original probability distribution of the data set was)?

I know that if that original data set is normal, then the variances would follow a chi-squared distribution. But what about in the case that it is not normal?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Can Bootstrap Resampling be used to Calculate a Confidence Interval for the Variance of a Data Set?

Yes, just as with many other statistics.

> I know that if you re-sample from a data set many times and calculate the mean each time, these means will follow a normal distribution (by the CLT).

It is not always the case that if you bootstrap a mean the bootstrap means will follow a normal distribution, even for distributions for which the CLT applies.

Here's an example where I resampled the mean for a sample of size $n=100$, where I resampled 10000 times:

[image]

It's not remotely normal.

The original sample consists of ninety-seven '0' values, and a '1', a '2' and a '100'.

Here's the (R) code I ran to generate the plot above:

```
 x <- c(rep(0,97),1,2,100)
 y <- replicate(10000,mean(sample(x,replace=TRUE)))
 plot(table(y),type="h")
```

The problem is that in this case the sample size (100) is too small for the CLT to apply with this sort of distribution shape; it doesn't matter how many times we resample it.

However, if the original sample size is much larger, the resampling distribution of sample means for something like this will be more normal-looking (though always discrete).

Here are the ecdfs when resampling the above data (black) and for values in the same proportions but with ten times as many values (red; that is, n=1000):

[image]

As we see, the distribution function when resampling the large sample does look much more normal.

> if I were to re-sample from a data set many times and calculate the variance each time, would these variances follow a certain distribution

No, for the same reason it's not necessarily true for the mean.

However, the CLT does also apply to the variance*; it's just that you can't argue that the CLT applies to bootstrap resampling simply by taking many resamples. If the *original* sample size is sufficiently large, that may (under the right conditions) tend to make the resampling distribution of means (and higher moments, if sufficiently-higher-order moments are finite) relatively close to a normal distribution (relative to its distribution in smaller samples, at least).

* that the CLT usually applies to the variance (assuming appropriate moments exist) is intuitive if you consider $s_n^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar x)^2$. Let $y_i = (x_i - \bar x)^2$; then $s_n^2 = \bar y$, so if the CLT applies to the $y$-variable, it can be applied to $s_n^2$. Now $s_{n-1}^2$ is just a scaled version of $s_n^2$; if the CLT applies to $s_n^2$ it will apply to  $s_{n-1}^2$. This outline of an argument is not completely solid, however, and there are some exceptions that you might not expect at first.